# Updating keys in app.config c#

Tags: c#

I am referring examples on internet to change settings in app.config , below is my code

```
string startupPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace(@"\bin\Debug", "")+ "App.Config";
                Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(startupPath);
                config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("MaintainBackup");
                config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("MaintainBackup", "No");
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

Problem is , it is not updating the key values in app.config (within root directory) 
 But when i use

```
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

it update the WinApp.vshost.exe.Config in bin folder .
Question1.]- Which config file my app is picking ? 
App.config in root directory 
 or WinApp.vshost.exe.Config in bin folder
Question 2.] If it is App.config in root directory than why it is not updating the key values

Comment: Because `App.config` only gets read once at the Startup of your Application. Simply restart your Application and the `ConfigurationManager` has your Values.

Comment: No , it does not works , Still the old values in app.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to make some order in the chaos:

There are two concepts mixed here:

1. App.Config vs AppName.exe.config
2. vshosts

**App.Config** is a development time file, after compilation it will become  AppName.exe.config and this file will be used by your application in runtime.

**vshosts.exe** is an host file of Visual Studio that is intended to give better performance while debugging from visual studio.

So, While debugging your application name will be AppName.vshosts.exe and therefore the configuraion file that will be used will be AppName.vshosts.exe.config